# Is there miscegenation in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

Is there miscegenation in the Star Wars universe?
Not only between humans, but also between humans and aliens?

Comment: I don't know, "miscegenation" is a pretty loaded word...

Comment: It probably would be helpful to indicate whether you're looking for whether there are mixed relationships, or if there's a prejudice against it, which "miscegenation" usually refers to.

Comment: Besides which they talk about "miscegenation between humans," so I think this question is worth trashing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And [hybrids](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Hybrid) can arise.

> Hybrids who were half-and-half, with each parent a full member of a different species, could look wildly different despite having the same basic genetic makeup. To use Twi'lek-human hybrids as an example, Shaeeah Lawquane looked almost fully Twi'lek, with her mottled skin color the only giveaway to her hybrid physiology, while her brother Jek possessed both lekku and hair. Jacen Syndulla, however, looked almost completely human apart from bright green hair and a slight green tint in parts of his skin, notably the tips of his ears.
>
> ### Known hybrid pairings
>
> - Humans and Espirions. (See: [Alder-Espirions](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Alder-Espirion))
> - Humans and Mirialans.
> - Humans and Twi'leks.
> - Humans and Theelin.
> - Quarrens and Mon Calamari.
> - Gungans and Gozzos (allegedly).

Comment: I just want to lampshade a rant about "each parent...different species" and the biological definition of "species." :-P

Comment: @DavidW I point out that there are many examples of hybrid organisms whose parents are members of different species on Earth, despite what the definition of species says.  Of course people from different planets are not just members of different species, or different genera, or different families, or different orders, or different classes, or different phyla, but of entirely different kingdoms at least. (unless something like the TNG episode "the Chase" happened in Star wars history.)

Comment: @M.A.Golding Your point about mixed-species hybrids ("mules") is well taken; I was admittedly generalizing for the sake of brevity.  But AFAIR it's never mentioned that all hybrids are sterile...

Comment: And not all hybrids are sterile in Earth biology. They're just much more likely to be.